# Addinga new argument to an existent funct(arg1, arg(n)...) or making a whole new function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, if-statement, methods

**Like the Title i want to make a method(in this case 'addItem') same as this one but accepting one more parameter**

```
(function (){return{
    addItem : function (type, des, val) {
        var newItem, ID;

        ID = dataStructure.allItems[type][dataStructure.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;

        if (dataStructure.allItems[type].length > 0){
            ID = dataStructure.allItems[type][dataStructure.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1
        }else {
            ID = 0;
        }


        //Create new ELEMENT based on 'exp' or 'inc' type
        if (type === 'exp'){
            newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
        }else if (type === 'inc'){
            newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
        }

        //Push it into our data structure
        dataStructure.allItems[type].push(newItem)

        //Return the new element
        return newItem;
    }
};})();
```

**I want to call( depending on some inputs) a method('addItem') from an object or invoke the other if the value of the input is 'X' .**

Comment: Is your question whether it is a better idea to add an optional argument to the existing function or to create a new function? Or are you asking how to implement it?

Comment: What i want to achieve is that from another function to call this method or the other one which will have an argument added but it will almost do the same thing but store one more argument to the data strucutre...     soooo i came with the idea that maybe i can just make a method borrow and then add it to another function that accepts one more parameter but doing the exact same thing as the method, but i actually dont have idea how to start coding this.